# Triple Summation Calculation Which Includes an Integral

Tags: numerics, summation

I am a beginner in Mathematica. I have to calculate the following summation:$$C_3(\alpha)=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{j,k,l=3}^{\infty}(2j+1)(2k+1)(2l+1)(C_jC_k+C_kC_l+C_lC_j)f_{jkl}$$ where $$f_{jkl}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^\pi\int_{\phi=0} ^{2\pi}sin{\theta}d{\theta}d{\phi}P_j(cos\theta)P_k(cos(\theta-\alpha)P_l[cot\alpha(sin\theta(1-cos\alpha)+cos\theta sin\alpha)]$$, $C_i=\frac{1}{i(i+1)}$ and $\alpha$ runs from 0 to 120 degrees. Here $P_j's$ are Legendre polynomials. I have to calculate $C_3({\alpha})$ for values of $\alpha$  in the above-mentioned range. The summation runs up to infinity from the theoretical formula but I guess after j,k,l=10 maybe the value of the summation will saturate. I have written the code to calculate the summation for $\alpha=20$ degrees:

```
c[j_] := 1/(j*(j + 1))
c[l_] := 1/(l*(l + 1))
c[k_] := 1/(k*(k + 1))
f[j_, k_, l_, \[Alpha]_] := 
 Assuming[\[Theta] \[Element] Reals && \[Phi] \[Element] Reals, 
  Integrate[
   LegendreP[j, Cos[\[Theta]]]*
    LegendreP[k, Cos[\[Theta] - \[Alpha] Degree]]*
    LegendreP[l, 
     Cot[\[Alpha] Degree]*(Sin[\[Theta]]*(1 - Cos[\[Alpha] Degree]) + 
        Cos[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Alpha] Degree])]*Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta],
     0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]]
N[Sum[(2j+1)*(2k+1)*(2l+1)*(C_j*C_k+C_k*C_l+C_l*C_j)*f[j, k, l, 20 Degree]/(12*\[Pi]), {j, 3, 10}, {k, 3, 10}, {l, 3, 10}]]
```

But I am unable to get the value of the summation the code never gets executed and runs for a long time.

Comment: What  geometric meaning has the $\cot\alpha(\sin\theta(1-\cos\alpha)+\cos\theta \sin\alpha)$ angle?

Comment: The argument of the Legendre polynomial is cotα(sinθ(1−cosα)+cosθsinα) which I found after some calculation. Actually, there are 4 unit vectors (\hat{n},\hat{a},\hat{b},\hat{c})in polar coordinates, and the arguments of Legendre polynomial is simply the dot product of \hat{n} with the other three unit vectors. From dot product cotα(sinθ(1−cosα)+cosθsinα) term arises.

Comment: I meant to say the arguments of Legendre polynomial cos(θ) comes from the dot product of \hat{n} and \hat{a}, cos(θ-α) comes from the dot product of  \hat{n} and \hat{b} and cotα(sinθ(1−cosα)+cosθsinα) comes from the dot product of  \hat{n} and \hat{c}. \hat{n} makes polar angle θ and azimuthal angle ϕ in spherical polar coordinates.

Comment: Something like this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4807073/435814 ?

Comment: Yes! Actually, that question you mentioned was posted by me. I assumed \hat{a} along the z-axis and found the modified expression as mentioned here.

Comment: You have terms like C_j, C_k, etc. in your sum, which should be c[j],c[k], etc. Since you want a numerical result, you might also try using NIntegrate instead of Integrate, and NSum directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were typos in the code you posted as I noted in the comment above. You had terms like C_j, etc., which should be c[j], etc. Since you're interested in a numerical result, I replaced Integrate with NIntegrate, and N@Sum with NSum. You had three c[_] definitions; one will suffice since they're basically the same formula. I also removed the Degree unit while tinkering, and just divided alpha by 180 in your f definition; you can revert this if you wish. I just wanted to declutter as much as possible while trying to get this to work.

After making the changes, it ran for a while without returning an answer, so I just ran f[__] by itself inside Table for a few values. I received a number of messages indicating convergence difficulties for the default NIntegrate option GlobalAdaptive, so I tried LocalAdaptive to see if it would handle your integrals more gracefully, and it did. I didn't see any more messages when I ran my test. I set up a function sumjlk to allow me to try varying the limits on your sum, to determine how long it might take. It ran acceptable fast for a small case, so I bumped up the limits to match your original problem.

Here's the modified code:

```
c[jkl_] := 1/(jkl*(jkl + 1))
f[j_, k_, l_, \[Alpha]_] := 
NIntegrate[
   LegendreP[j, Cos[\[Theta]]]*
    LegendreP[k, Cos[\[Theta] - \[Alpha]]]*
    LegendreP[l, 
     Cot[\[Alpha]]*(Sin[\[Theta]]*(1 - Cos[\[Alpha]]) + 
        Cos[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Alpha]])]*Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta],
     0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]},Method->"LocalAdaptive"];

sumjlk[jmax_,kmax_,lmax_] := NSum[(2j+1)*(2k+1)*(2l+1)*(c[j] c[k]+c[k]*c[l]+c[l]*c[j])*f[j, k, l, 20 Degree], 
    {j, 3, jmax}, {k, 3, kmax}, {l, 3, lmax}]/(12*\[Pi]);
```

And this is the result I obtained after roughly one minute:

```
sumjlk[10,10,10]
```

EDIT: I left out a factor of Pi in my earlier post when converting degrees to radians. After fixing and rerunning, this is the result.

```
(* 1.30704*)
```